# Compiling source code fundamentals: general steps to compile some program for any Linux

Tags: software-compilation, open-source

I have compiled **source codes** some times for some Linux programs, so I was wondering if it could be done too for **Raspberry**.

I have a **Raspberry Pi 2** running **Ubuntu v14.04.2 LTS**.
I don't know if the compiling procedure is **generic** for any (or most) programs, so I have decided to try with a rather simple one: [PeerVPN](http://www.peervpn.net/), a simple tool that creates a new *virtual interface* device connected to some server.

[Here](http://www.peervpn.net/files/peervpn-0-042.tar.gz) is the source code.
But when **trying to compile**, I get:

```
luis@Zarzamoro:~/Temporal/PeerVPN/peervpn-0-042$ ls -la
total 120
drwxr-xr-x 5 luis luis  4096 Jan 21 00:28 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 luis luis  4096 Jun 28 02:17 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 luis luis  9156 Jan 21 00:25 config.ic
-rw-r--r-- 1 luis luis  3737 Jan 21 00:25 console.ic
drwxr-xr-x 2 luis luis  4096 Jan 21 00:25 ethernet
-rw-r--r-- 1 luis luis  2012 Jan 21 00:25 globals.ic
-rw-r--r-- 1 luis luis  8516 Jan 21 00:25 init.ic
drwxr-xr-x 2 luis luis  4096 Jan 21 00:25 libp2psec
-rw-r--r-- 1 luis luis 35147 Jan 21 00:25 license.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 luis luis  8262 Jan 21 00:25 mainloop.ic
-rw-r--r-- 1 luis luis   160 Jan 21 00:25 Makefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 luis luis  3420 Jan 21 00:28 peervpn.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 luis luis  7067 Jan 21 00:25 peervpn.conf
drwxr-xr-x 2 luis luis  4096 Jan 21 00:25 platform
-rw-r--r-- 1 luis luis  3600 Jan 21 00:25 pwd.ic
luis@Zarzamoro:~/Temporal/PeerVPN/peervpn-0-042$ sudo apt-get install gcc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
gcc is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
luis@Zarzamoro:~/Temporal/PeerVPN/peervpn-0-042$ make
cc -O2   -c -o peervpn.o peervpn.c
peervpn.c:22:28: fatal error: openssl/engine.h: No such file or directory
 #include <openssl/engine.h>
                            ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [peervpn.o] Error 1
```

What is **wrong** here? Any missing library that can be fixed?
Is this some fatal error telling it is **not possible** to compile this source for Raspberry?
Or generic Linux sources can **never** be compiled on Raspberry?
Do I need something like an **appropriate guide** to follow for this task?

Additional Points:

- Like GCC, **OpenSSL** is installed, at its latest version.

Answer (score 2):

seems like you are missing the development openssl package.
you can try this:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Comment: Indeed, after installing such package, everything worked like a charm, thanks you.